# Characters found after end of SQL statement query problem

Tags: ms-access

```
SELECT Booking.ID, Booking.[Lecture Name], Booking.[Booking Date], Booking.[Booking Time (Start)], Booking.[Booking Time (Finish)], Booking.[Utility Room]
FROM Booking;
WHERE [Lecture Name] AND [Booking Date] AND [Booking Time (Start)] AND [Booking Time (Finish)] AND [Utility Room];
```

Comment: You have a stray semicolon in `FROM Booking;` ... but just correcting that alone still leaves your query with other problems.

Comment: Strongly advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention. Never seen anyone do a WHERE clause like although it will process. Record where any field is null will not be retrieved. Access query object will automatically add <> False under each field.